# Suppressing rasterio verbosity

Tags: python, rasterio

I have the following script using rasterio:

```
if not os.path.isfile(out_dir + os.sep + name_adm1 + '.tif'):
    with rasterio.drivers():
        with rasterio.open(constants.ras_cmask) as src:
            b1 = src.read(1)

            profile = src.profile
            profile.update(
                dtype=rasterio.float64,
                count=1,
                compress='lzw')

        ndvi = b1.astype(float)
        ndvi[ndvi != int(num_ID)] = np.nan

        with rasterio.open(out_dir + os.sep + name_adm1 + '.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:
            dst.write(ndvi.astype(rasterio.float64), 1)
```

However, when I run it, it produces a lot of messages like this:

```
03/13/2016 13:40:22  rasterio           DEBUG        Creating a not-responsible GDALEnv in drivers()
03/13/2016 13:40:22  rasterio           DEBUG        Got coordinate system
03/13/2016 13:40:22  rasterio           DEBUG        Got coordinate system
03/13/2016 13:40:22  rasterio           DEBUG        Input CRS: {'init': u'epsg:4326'}
03/13/2016 13:40:22  rasterio           DEBUG        Exported WKT: GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
03/13/2016 13:40:22  rasterio           DEBUG        Self CRS: {'init': u'epsg:4326'}
03/13/2016 13:40:22  rasterio           DEBUG        Got coordinate system
03/13/2016 13:40:22  rasterio           DEBUG        Got coordinate system
03/13/2016 13:40:23  rasterio           DEBUG        Option: ('BLOCKYSIZE', '1')

03/13/2016 13:40:23  rasterio           DEBUG        Option: ('COMPRESS', 'LZW')

03/13/2016 13:40:23  rasterio           DEBUG        Option: ('BLOCKXSIZE', '7200')

03/13/2016 13:40:23  rasterio           DEBUG        Option: ('TILED', 'FALSE')

Warning 6: driver ENVI does not support creation option BLOCKYSIZE
Warning 6: driver ENVI does not support creation option COMPRESS
Warning 6: driver ENVI does not support creation option BLOCKXSIZE
Warning 6: driver ENVI does not support creation option TILED
Warning 6: driver ENVI does not support creation option BLOCKYSIZE
Warning 6: driver ENVI does not support creation option COMPRESS
Warning 6: driver ENVI does not support creation option BLOCKXSIZE
```

Is there a way to either suppress these, or redirect to logging file?

Comment: Which version of rasterio are you using ?

Comment: Upgrade! 0.25 is pretty old.

Comment: thanks @sgillies, I am having issues upgrading to 0.30, the pip install rolls back to 0.25

Answer (score 7):

Try adding this to your script:

```
from rasterio import logging

log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

You can substitute `ERROR` with other levels: `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARN`, `FATAL`.

Comment: thanks @bosth, this does help some, I am at `logging.ERROR` level, but can still see 'Warning`s

Comment: Python's default log level is WARNING, so you shouldn't be seeing those DEBUG level messages except by the choices made by your environment. Are you using a Jupyter/IPython notebook?

Comment: thanks @sgillies, I just noticed your reply. I am not using any notebook, just straight up scripts.